# Lost of Receipts With the App Store from Server

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We have a gamme with iAP feature with some issue recently.

Currently the device is to purchase items from Appstore
and the device will send the receipt to server for validation.

After validated, server will give the products (e.g. coins) to player's account.
It ran well for long and there is a user reported that they cannot receive coins from the game.

The user said they have receive confirmation from AppStore but no increase in coins.
Thus, we are thinking if the user has sudden data lost in network and the receipt was not sending to server. (or sent but somehow lost packet)

would like to know:
 1. how to search out this purchase history? by code, in Appstore or iTune connects?
 2. is there any best practice code to recovery lost receipt or validate the receipt?

Thanks very much

Comment: I've been wondering about this myself. My app has IAPs. I've not run into this situation, but wondering what to do if it does. Can the user send you a receipt provided by Apple? Have you contacted iTunesConnect?

Comment: Not contacted yet... just think this should be a common question for every app with iAP in store...

Comment: You would think so, yes. Apparently no one is willing to share here tho! Receipt from customer?

Comment: Likely this is really related to financial and no one wants to share... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has responded me about this issue.
From their explanation, it sounds like a specific case that the transaction is not completed in their side but it gives a transaction completed message to user.